# How to use double angle identities to find length 'd'?

Tags: trigonometry

Edit: Ok the question has now been amended by my tutor as I highlighted it was not possible to solve.

A pole is tensioned at point A as shown below, if the angles are to be kept the same, then using a suitable double angle identity determine the distance $d$: 
[image: See illustration.]

Edit: *Note that triangle ACB is not a right angled triangle.* Should now read: 
Note that triangle ACD is not a right angled triangle.

By using $$\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$$
My working is:
$$\cos x=\frac d3$$
$$\cos 2x=\frac d3$$
therefore:
$$\frac d3=2(\frac d3)^2-1$$

Now becomes solvable as a quadratic equation

Comment: I improved the math formatting a little.  You can read more about using MathJax and $\LaTeX$ in [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Yes I noticed, thanks.  This is my first post so still getting my head around the formatting side of it.  How did you get this image to display within the post?

Comment: This question needs explanation especially for non-english readers. I get nothing from it. Please explain it more if you can.

Comment: Which part needs further explanation? I guess part of the problem is that I don't fully understand it myself or know if my approach is correct, sorry

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was unable to locate the pole. Now located. Tell me one thing, Is A not in air? I mean if pole is vertical fixed on ground.

Comment: Readers will have to rely on you to be the expert on what you are asking.  For example, you wrote: "Note that triangle ACB is not a right angled triangle."  It isn't clear to me how to make sense of the problem unless one assumes that it is a right angle triangle, and then we can "solve" for distance $d$ in terms of $m$ (they are proportional).

Comment: Apologies if I haven’t been clear. This is a question I was given and after a few attempts my opinion was that it could not be solved without it being a right triangle. I was assured that it could be so it is helpful to have confirmation that my initial assumption was correct. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the quadratic equation when in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ you can use the formula:
$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}$$

Answer (score 0):

I will interpret the problem as "*given a point $C$ on a segment $BD$ such as $BC=b$ and $CD=c$, what is the distance $d$ from $A$ to $B$ such that $BC$ and $CD$ have the same angular diameter?*"

Using the law of cosines in triangles $ABC$ and $ACD$ we get
$$c^2=2^2+3^2-2\times 2\times 3 \cos x$$
$$b^2=d^2+2^2-4d\cos x$$
so that $$\cos x=\dfrac{13-c^2}{12}$$ and $$b^2=d^2+4-\dfrac{4d(13-c^2)}{12}$$
The last equation is quadratic in $d$ and easy to solve.

Comment: Of course you can use the cosine law in triangle $ABD$ if you want to use $\cos 2x$. If the position of $A$ and the value of $x$ aren't specified, you need the values of $b$ and $c$ to find them, unless $ABD$ is a right triangle.

Answer (score -1):

$\cos(x)\neq \frac{2}{3}$ because the angle $\widehat{ACD} \neq \frac{\pi}{2}$.